# Tracking multiple contact forms in Google analytics

Tags: javascript, forms, google-analytics

I have to track 2 contact forms on a website. The first contact form is working fine. We have added a separate code for 2nd contact form. Here are the code snippets for the forms:

Form1:

```
function googleAnalyticsEvents() {
   ga('send', 'event', 'Contact Us Form', 'Submit', 'Contact Form Submitted');
}
```

Form2:

```
function googleAnalyticsEventsByb() {
   ga('send', 'event', 'Build Your Bird Form', 'Submit', 'Build Your Bird Form Submitted');
}
```

When the form2 is submitted on the website, the code for form1 invokes and it shows up in the Real time section of Google Analytics.

Can someone please tell me what the exact cause for this would be?

Answer (score 0):

There might be an error in the way the forms' "Submit" callbacks are set. Could you provide the code used to bind to the `onsubmit` events?